# COBOL Program not writing file

Tags: file, cobol

HI all,

I have a sequential file with DISP = (MOD, CATLG, CATLG)
My program does an OPEN I-O  and it is supposed to write to the file
however, when job ends successfully, the file is still empty..

am i missing something?

```
FILE
REJECT   DD DSN=FILEA,         
            DISP=(MOD,CATLG,CATLG),UNIT=TESTPACK,
            DCB=(LRECL=109,BLKSIZE=0,RECFM=FB),  
            SPACE=(TRK,(3,1),RLSE)               

COBOL Program:
FD  REJECT-FILE                            
    RECORDING MODE IS F                    
    LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD             
    BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS               
    RECORD CONTAINS 109 CHARACTERS         
    DATA RECORD IS REJC-OUT-RECORD.        
01  REJC-OUT-RECORD             PIC X(109).


ADD-REJECTS-HEADER.                                 
    SKIP1                                           
    READ REJECT-FILE INTO RECORD-IN                 
    EVALUATE WS-STATUS                              
        WHEN '00'                                   
            CONTINUE                                
        WHEN '10'                                   
            CLOSE REJECT-FILE                       
            OPEN I-O REJECT-FILE                    
            WRITE REJC-OUT-RECORD FROM WS-HEADER-REJ
    END-EVALUATE.
```

Comment: Hi gurus! I finally got it. Seems that my version of COBOL does not support WRITE in I-O mode...thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to "CLOSE" the REJECT-FILE after your "WRITE".

Also there are many more possible condition codes than '00' and '10'.

I would suggest you replace the "WHEN '10'" with " OTHERWISE" to catch all non zero conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you should to do to make your program a bit "safer" with respect to file operations are:

1) Check and react to the `FILE-STATUS` on every file operation, OPEN, READ, WRITE and CLOSE.

2) Provide a catch-all for unexpected conditions. You

are only checking for "normal" and "end-of-file" conditions. A lot of other things might be indicated as well. See [this reference](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/igy3lr31/6.1.8.9.1?SHELF=&DT=20060329140556&CASE=).

It looks like you may be trying to read from and write to the same physical file. All of the I/O operations (OPEN/READ/WRITE) refer to the same file. Are you attempting to open the file for sequential access and upon reaching the end-of-file, switch to I-O then add
a new record?

It would be very helpful if you showed the `FILE-CONTROL` paragraph as well. This will indicate how you are trying to access the file. I think there may be problems with the access mode specified under `FILE-CONTROL` and the OPEN/CLOSE/READ and WRITEs in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`. For example, I don't see where you are specifying the record key for the `I-O` write operation.

Provide the `FILE-CONTROL` paragraph and tell us a bit more about what this program is doing. Also, give us the value of `FILE-STATUS` we might be able to offer more help at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Has the file EVER been opened?  If you just freshly allocated it with MOD, it will not have a proper EOF marker.  Sometimes you will see people use IEBGENER to allocate NEW datasets an copy 0 records to them to get the EOF marker written.